# Sending Multiple Cells to my SharePoint with rst.Fields

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ado

Pardon any errors my VBA skills are not great.

So, I'm attempting to upload excel data to a SharePoint list and I followed some tutorials to understand how I can accomplish this within a macro and I'm using ADO and SQL to achieve this. I got the connection working because in a separate Macro I was able to pull my data and send singular rows of data but I want to send several rows worth of data in the excel and I tried a common loop but it didn't work. Ideally i'd like it if I could use the Macro to upload Row 2 to Row X (LastRow) I tried looping but either I don't understand the syntax of this or I can't loop it like how I figured I could.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddNew_SP()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [1];"

'open connection

With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=MySite;LIST=MyGUID;"
    .Open
End With

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
'For i = 2 To LastRow
rst.AddNew
    'rst.Fields("Department")=["A" + "i"]
    'rst.Fields("Section#") = ["B" + "i"]
    'rst.Fields("Operation#") = ["C" + "i"]
    'rst.Fields("Job") = ["D" + "i"]
    'rst.Fields("Program") = ["L" + "i"]
rst.Update
'Next i
If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: "I tried a common loop but it didn't work" - what happened instead of it working?

Comment: Syntax Error, I'm not well-versed in VBA so I wrote it syntax for Column A Cell i wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`["B" + "2"]` (eg) is not the same as `[B2]` - using square brackets to refer to ranges in VBA is best avoided: it's not worth saving a few characters over `Range()`, `Cells()` etc

Try this:

```
Dim rw As Range
'...
'...

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
For i = 2 To LastRow
     With ActiveSheet.Rows(i)
         rst.AddNew
         rst.Fields("Department")=.Parent.Range("A2").value
         rst.Fields("Section#") = .Cells(2).Value
         rst.Fields("Operation#") = .Cells(3).Value
         rst.Fields("Job") = .Cells(4).Value
         rst.Fields("Program") = .Cells(12).Value
     End with
     rst.UpdateBatch
Next i
```

Comment: While this did work for me, I'm curious as to what exactly .Cells(X).Value does? could you explain it a tad, I'm not one to just take an answer and run off.

Comment: @RobertFarmer you're working off `ActiveSheet.Rows(i)`, so with `i=2` you're looking at `.Rows(2)` - that's a `Range` object representing the entire row. So going `.Cells(2)` against that range will give you the 2nd cell, i.e. the cell in the 2nd column aka "B" - that *also* returns a `Range` object, this time representing only a single cell; `.Value` retrieves the underlying value of that cell.

Comment: @RobertFarmer meanwhile `[B2]` is *also* working off the `ActiveSheet`, but implicitly. The bracketed expression is a string, that is then given to `Application.Evaluate`, which makes Excel evaluate the string/bracketed-expression in the context of the active sheet, so `[B2]` gives you a `Range` object representing that cell in the active sheet. Except the expression `"A" + "i"` evaluates to a worksheet error, because if you did `="A" + "i"` in a cell, that's what you'd get.

Comment: Okay, so now I've discovered now that I've applied this to my full data set some of the items seem to be duplicating 2-3 times. My Data set currently contains 842 Items, and at the end of running the macro I uploaded 953 items